# Flatpak does not update its apps when run via cron

Tags: 20.04, cron, flatpak

This simple script runs correctly when launched manually:

```
#!/bin/sh

flatpak -y update 2>&1 >> ~/cron/cron-flatpak.log
```

When run with `00 07 * * * sh ~/cron/cron-flatpak.sh` (same regular user, not root crontab), it produces the following:

```
Looking for updates…


 1.     org.chromium.Chromium.Codecs    stable  u   flathub < 1.1 MB
 2.     org.chromium.Chromium.Locale    stable  u   flathub < 112.8 kB (partial)
 3.     org.qbittorrent.qBittorrent stable  u   flathub < 8.3 MB



Updating 1/3…                                                                 
Warning: Failed to get revokefs-fuse socket from system-helper: Flatpak system operation GetRevokefsFd not allowed for user

Updating 1/3… ██▌                   13%  41.1 kB/s
Updating 1/3… ████████████████████ 100%  674.8 kB/s
Updating 1/3… ████████████████████ 100%  674.8 kB/s
Updating 2/3…                                                                 
Warning: Failed to get revokefs-fuse socket from system-helper: Flatpak system operation GetRevokefsFd not allowed for user

Updating 2/3… ████████████████████ 100%  592 bytes/s
Updating 3/3…                                                                 
Warning: Failed to get revokefs-fuse socket from system-helper: Flatpak system operation GetRevokefsFd not allowed for user

Updating 3/3… ████████████████████ 100%  0 bytes/s
Updates complete.
```

Afterwards, the versions seem to match what's listed on flathub.io, but the script tries to update everything over and over again on each run. Any suggestions?

**ETA:** Okay people, I'll be testing the approaches you suggested and I will accept one answer or the other after I manage to make the thing work. Going to take a while since every single iteration requires a new app version rolled out on flathub.

Comment: You can install specific versions of flatpaks, such as older versions, using ```flatpak remote-info --log flathub PACKAGE_NAME``` to list the commit history, and then 'update' the flatpak to that specific version: ```flatpak update --commit=COMMIT_STRING PACKAGE_NAME```. Use the ```--user``` flag for user packages. For system packages, sudo is required install a specific commit.

Comment: @wizardpurple Rolling my test app back to an older commit saved me a lot of time. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not so much a solution as a workaround, or possible clue, but installing Chromium with the `--user` flag (flatpak uses `--system` by default) and updating works fine in cron.

```
flatpak install flathub org.chromium.Chromium # default, has cron issues
flatpak install --user flathub org.chromium.Chromium # no cron issues
```

Unfortunately, I'm unsure why the ability to update system flatpaks is dropped in cron—<strike>at least for the Chromium flatpak since it looks like the third flatpak was able to update just. Maybe the issue is with that particular flatpak.</strike>

Edit: I missed the third error in the output, it was not unique to Chromium.

Edit 2: Just some further clarification/steps for using flatpak's `--user` flag. Since system and user packages are managed separately, this means adding/removing remotes, installing, and updating must also be done separately. A user package cannot pull from a system remote and vice versa.

```
# add a user remote
flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists --user REMOTE_NAME REMOTE_ADDRESS

# updates just user packages
flatpak update --user
```

Comment: Since cron runs its jobs as the same interactive user who executed `crontab -e`, the only difference between installing flatpak apps for system and for user must be in directories, right?

Comment: Yes, ```--user``` packages will be installed to ```$HOME/.local/share/flatpak/app/``` and ```--system``` (the default method) are in ```/var/lib/flatpak/app/```

Comment: Accepting this one because it's cleaner ideologically, especially when user sets up flatpak from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

Jobs run through `cron`, or `at`, or `batch`, aren't run in the same runtime environment that you have on your desktop. None of your `PATH` changes, or other environment  variable settings are automatically propagated to  your `cron` job. For example, there's no `$DISPLAY`, so GUI programs need special treatment (read `man xhost`).

One can set environment variables for all one's `cron` jobs in the `crontab` file
Read `man 5 crontab`.

Look at the results of  `echo "=== set ===";set;echo "=== env ===";env | sort;echo "=== alias ===";alias` in each of your environments.

Since the `command` part of the `crontab` line is, by default,  interpreted by `/bin/sh`, which has a simpler syntax than `/bin/bash`, I recommend having `command` be a call to a `bash` script  (executable, mounted, starts with `#!/bin/bash`) which sets up the environment,  then calls the desired program.

Comment: The output of `set` for my user account is 72 KB and for cron is 406 bytes. Even after excluding the obviously irrelevant differences, testing it line-by-line would take years. Is there a way to just load my whole user environment into cron? I'm reading up on sourcing the environment variables now; pretty sure it's a dead end because it sounds too obvious. Would have been mentioned somewhere if it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Found a cheap and dirty solution: run flatpak via cron with `sudo`. There are at least 3 ways to do it; I went with adding flatpak to `sudoers` like this:

```
Cmnd_Alias FLATPAK = /usr/bin/flatpak
myusername ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: FLATPAK
```

The script changes accordingly:

```
#!/bin/sh

sudo /usr/bin/flatpak -y update 2>&1 >> ~/cron/cron-flatpak.log
```

With these modifications, everything updates without a hitch. The real reason is most likely not the privileges per se but some other change in the environment, but at least it does not make me reinstall everything.

If anyone thinks it's a bad idea, please explain why.

Comment: What about running it from root's crontab? No need to add flatpak to sudoers that way.

Comment: This would be the fourth way. I'm still curious why it works, but we'll probably never know.